# Pegar resultado do id e jogar para input

Tags: php, javascript, html

Não estou sabendo pesquisar e caso possa haver o mesmo tipo de dificuldade por aqui, me desculpem.

Estou com uma dificuldade, estou querendo pegar o valor que é apresentado após o submit e colocar esse valor com o id="resultado" em um input para postriormente enviar em um formulário.
Só que o valor que apresenta está vindo como texto e eu quero levar esse texto para um input.

**Exemplo:
TEXTO: R$ 0,00**
Pegar esse resultado e jogar no input.

O que eu já fiz e posso imaginar o que pode ser:

JS:

```
$("#resultado").text("R$ " + (bandeirada + distancia * bandeira + (duracao / 3) * tempo_parado).toFixed(2));
```

Não sei se o valor .text possa haver, mas tem algum outro tipo de valor?

HTML:

```
<td class="text-primary" name="resultado" id="resultado"></td>
```

Tenho um modal do bootstrap na mesma página e no caso se fosse de input pra input eu sei como fazer. Agora de Texto pra input não to sabendo :(

**EDIT:**
Consegui apresentar o valor após submit, alterando o .text para .val
Agora quero levar o valor após submit para o input no modal.
Segue imagem: https://i.ibb.co/dcxCkrR/psc.png

**EDIT2:**
Agora estou com outro impasse, conforme imagem
https://i.ibb.co/NxFXpYZ/input.png

Os valores que eu pego e passo para outro input são valores após submit.

Javascript após submit para pegar os valores e onclick="setValue":

```
function setValue () {
    var nome = document.getElementById("end").value;
    document.getElementById("destino_form").value = nome;
};
```

E quando eu quero pegar um valor 'resultado' de um input e passar para outro depois que eu dei submit?

Obrigado!

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, você quer pegar o texto de dentro desse `td id="resultado"`, é isso?

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/dcxCkrR/psc.png - Segue uma imagem do valor apresentado após submit e quero q apresente no modal.

Comment: Então, você pode dar um `.val()` no input pra ler, e um `.val(valor)` pra atribuir, mas você comentou q já sabe fazer isso, se for pra pegar um texto é da mesma forma, `.html()` lê o html q tem dentro do seletor, `.html( valor )` atribui

Comment: Eu fiz uma nova edição, como edit2

Comment: Você fez a função em jquery inves de javascript agora, mas o procedimento é o mesmo, e a sua função parece estar ok, você pega com `.value` e da um set com `.value = valor`, qual seria a sua dúvida? se essa função nao está dando certo, talvez seja na referenciação dos elementos na DOM ou como você ta chamando ela

Comment: Consegui com a mesma função apresentada acima! Obrigado Luis! eu estava errando realmente em uma referenciação de um name. Valeu!

Comment: Show, que bom que resolveu!!

Comment: Como está usando Bootstrap daria para fazer com o `$('iddomodal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {...}` do próprio modal do Bootstrap. Mas se já resolveu deixa para lá.